# How do I do Laravel form validation when value of one field decides validity of the other field

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-6

I have a form. Type field is a drop-down and has only two possible values. Second field is bcode.
E.g.
if table has data like-

```
ID  TYPE  BCODE
1     1     2
2     1     3
3     2     2
4     1     4
5     2     2
```

Now I am making a popup form to insert record in this table. So if type is entered 1 and bcode is entered 2,3 or 4 its already in table so it will be invalid but any other numeric value will be valid. Similarly if type is entered 2 then bcode can't be anything other than 2,3 or 4. All other values will be invalid.

I read the Laravel docs here-
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#custom-validation-rules
But did not find anything.
Anyone tried something similar?

Comment: I dont unserstand your question

Comment: It seems like you are trying to make a custom validation rule. How far along did you get? `php artisan help make:rule` will help you understand how to use the built in generator for this.  That will put a new rule class in the app/Rules folder where you can implement what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table structure is like in your example and its called `type_bcode`, I'm offering the following solution:

1. Create custom rule by running `php artisan make:rule TypeBcode` 
   It should look like this:

   ```
   private $type;

   public function __construct($type)
   {
       $this->type = $type;
   }
   public function passes($attribute, $value)
   {
       $type_bcode = DB::table('type_bcode')
           ->where('type', $this->type)
           ->get()
           ->pluck('bcode')
           ->toArray();

       return in_array($value, $type_bcode);
   }
   public function message()
   {
       return 'The validation error message.';
   }
   ```
2. In your controllers store function do this:

   ```
   public function store(Request $request)
   {
       $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
           'type' => 'required',
           'bcode' => ['required', new TypeBcode($request->type)],
       ]);
       if ($validator->fails()) {
           //some action
       }
       //some action
   }
   ```

Hope this will help

Comment: Not exactly what I was expecting but logic is correct.I did as bellow & it worked-  
      $typeset = array_unique(DB::table('type_bcode')->get()->pluck('bcode')->toArray());
        if($this->type == 1 && in_array($value, $typeset)){
            return false;
        }
        elseif($this->type == 2)
        {
            return in_array($value, $typeset);
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
Only I was unable to get to work was unique values with distinct.Thats why I used array_unique function.If you have a better way please suggest.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Validator side code is pretty much same so not included in my comment.